# How do I get the words without these characters?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I want to get from text file `1.txt` only the words that don't contain the letters `a`, `b` and `c` and export it to `2.txt`, but this does not return anything:

```
grep -o [^abc]*$ 1.txt > 2.txt
```

How do I get the words that don't contain `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: You probably need to quote the pattern, among other things.

Comment: are you just looking for individual words or for the lines?

Comment: perhaps something like `grep -iv "[abc]" 1.txt > 2.txt`

Comment: try these grep '^[abc]+$' 1.txt > 2.txt or grep -Eiv '[^abc]' 1.txt > 2.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep you can use

```
grep -w -o '[^abc]*' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

The relevant pieces from `man` are:

```
  -w, --word-regexp
          Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words...

  -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty)  parts  of  a  matching line...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -w -o -P '[^abc\s]*' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

So whitespace aren't allowed in the middle of the 'word' too.

I included the -P flag too solely in order to interpret the regex as Perl and allow the \s placeholder.

```
 -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
```